# Why is this code throwing 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' (SQlite)?

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception

I am having trouble understanding why I am getting this exception thrown !

This is the code :

```
public static List<Employee> LoadEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
                {
                    cnn.Open();                   
                    string query = "select * from Employee;";
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, cnn);
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            emp[i].Id = reader.GetString(0);
                            emp[i].Name = reader.GetString(1);
                            emp[i].Gender = reader.GetString(2);
                            emp[i].Department = reader.GetString(3);
                            emp[i].Doj = reader.GetString(4);
                            emp[i].Email = reader.GetString(5);
                            emp[i].Phone = reader.GetString(6);
                            i++;
                        }

                    }
                    return emp;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                emp = null;
                return emp;
            }
        }
```

I tried debugging and found that -
id = 'emp[i].Id' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll

I am not understanding why it throwing it because i have initialized i = 0;

Comment: Oh god! That was a silly mistake . Thankyou for pointing it out @Rafalon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
```

At this point, `emp` is **empty**, but you try accessing items by using `emp[i]` when it's still empty.
You should use `emp.Add(new Employee());` at some point if you don't want the list to be empty anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<Employee> LoadEmployees()
{
        List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>(); // basically you have created new List<Employee> which is at the moment is empty. so if you try to do emp[0].Name, you will get exception

        try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                cnn.Open();                   
                string query = "select * from Employee;"; // fetching employees from database
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, cnn);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Employee e = new Employee(); // create new instance of employee object and initialize it's members and then add it in emp object.
                        e.Id = reader.GetString(0);
                        e.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                        e.Gender = reader.GetString(2);
                        e.Department = reader.GetString(3);
                        e.Doj = reader.GetString(4);
                        e.Email = reader.GetString(5);
                        e.Phone = reader.GetString(6);
                        emp.Add(e);
                    }

                }

                return emp;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            emp = null;
            return emp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou @Johnny for answering!

Comment: It's my pleasure @Ia27